# HTML - Create multiple forms out of one form template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I currently have multiple forms that are similar but have small changes. First, the user choses the form from a drop-down menu and then the form is shown below.

My forms looks like this.

1. Form 1

   - Customer Name
   - Phone Number
   - Address
2. Form 2

   - Customer Name
   - Is married?
3. Form 3

   - Customer Name
   - Social Security Number
   - Address

My code looks something like this.

```
<select onchange="changeOptions(this)">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="form1">f1</option>
    <option value="form2">f2</option>
    <option value="form3">f3</option>
</select>

<form class="className" name="form1" id="form1" style="display:none">
---form---
<form class="className" name="form2" id="form2" style="display:none">
---form---
<form class="className" name="form3" id="form3" style="display:none">
---form---
<script>
    function changeOptions(selectEl) {
        let selectedValue = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value;
        let subForms = document.getElementsByClassName('className')
        for (let i = 0; i < subForms.length; i += 1) {
            if (selectedValue === subForms[i].name) {
                subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block')
            } else {
                subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way to create a 'main' form that has all the form elements and then specify which element to use in each form? The method I'm using right now works fine but there is too much repeated code and probably won't scale correctly if I try to make a change in one of the elements (since I would have to change each one of them and it will be easy to make mistakes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need three different forms, just have one form with all of the fields set as hidden. Then give each field a class matching which form that field should be shown. Then simply show the matching fields based on the selected value.

```js
select_form = document.querySelector(".select_form");
fields = document.querySelectorAll(".field");

select_form.addEventListener("change", function() {
  fields.forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
  });
  show = document.querySelectorAll("." + this.value);
  show.forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "block";
  });
});
```

```css
.field {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="select_form">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="form1">f1</option>
  <option value="form2">f2</option>
  <option value="form3">f3</option>
</select>

<form>
  <div class="field form1 form2">ONLY form1 and 2</div>
  <div class="field form3">ONLY form3</div>
</form>
```